# After updating RCP client target from 4.17 to 4.24 the BindingService manager can't be initialized

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

After updating client target from 4.17 to 4.24 I am getting an exception in the Workbench on line 2247. This is happening after calling  PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, advisor);

```
        StartupThreading.runWithoutExceptions(new StartupRunnable() {

            @Override
            public void runWithException() {
                BindingManager.DEBUG = Policy.DEBUG_KEY_BINDINGS;
                bindingManager = e4Context.get(BindingManager.class);
                bindingService[0] = ContextInjectionFactory.make(BindingService.class, e4Context); // Throws an exception
            }
        });
```

The error I get is 'org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "BindingService.manager": no actual value was found for the argument "BindingManager"' and the application cannot start.

There was a similiar problem here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400265 and making the BindingManager optional was a solution, I wonder if I could make it optional in BindinService somehow.

Is there any way to force the BindingManager to be loaded and/or set so the application starts?

Comment: The BindingService should have been put in the context by `org.eclipse.ui.internal.BindingToModelProcessor` started from the `org.eclipse.ui.workbench` `plugin.xml`

Comment: In my case none of the public methods in BindingToModelProcessor are called before  PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, advisor) is called, can I provoke BindingToModelProcessor to execute before thw workbench is created? Is there a way of making the BindingManager of the BindingService optional?

Comment: No, it has to be run. There is something wrong with your setup.

Comment: Interesting, I experimented with the launcher and switched from "run a product" to "run an application" and now BindingToModelProcessor is called early on and the application starts, very odd, any ideas why this helps?

Comment: Your `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` definition is probably wrong.

Comment: The only thing in there that could be funky is my bespoke modelResourceHandler, which is loading user profiles. I take it out and I can start up as a product. However, I need my ProfileResourceHandler and it isn't throwing exceptions. I wonder what eclipse doesn't like about it.